# WordPress Custom Post Type Duplicate Postname Permalink

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks

I have a custom post type, 'Videos', in WordPress and am using the `All Import` plugin to import ~1000 pages of video content I scraped and saved in a CSV.

The permalinks I would want should be like so:

```
mysite.wpengine.com/videos/2010/fall/CompanyX
mysite.wpengine.com/videos/2011/spring/CompanyX
mysite.wpengine.com/videos/2011/summer/CompanyX
```

The thing is I'm getting this instead:

```
mysite.wpengine.com/videos/2010/fall/CompanyX
mysite.wpengine.com/videos/2011/spring/CompanyX-2
mysite.wpengine.com/videos/2011/summer/CompanyX-3
```

Because the postname for all of the Videos is the same, WP automatically adds `-2` or `-3` to the permalink and it won't let me change this. Does anyone know how I could solve this? I thought adding the year and season to the permalink would allow having the same postname but this isn't the case.

Comment: The unique post name is core to the way WordPress works.  The post names will need to be unique in your CSV file prior to import.

Comment: @LukePeterson I was afraid this was the case. I suppose I don't absolutely need to have the permalinks the way I want but I need to do redirects from the oldsite in which case the `-2` or `-3` tacked onto the permalinks leaves me puzzled as to how I can do a simple redirect and not write ~1000 custom ones.

I have `oldsite.com/videos/2010/fall/CompanyX` to `newsite.com/videos/2010/fall/CompanyX-n` where the last `n` could be anywhere from 2 to ~10 or more but I can't really know for sure without checking manually.